# Getting rid of the excess elements that TinyMCE inserts into text

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

I've noticed that when using TinyMCE 5 inline it inserts a load of extra elements that I really don't want.

```
<span id="_mce_caret" data-mce-bogus="1" data-mce-type="format-caret">﻿H</span><sup>2</sup>O
```

what I'd expect is

```
H<sup>2</sup>O
```

Is there any way within Tiny to stop doing this? Alternatively I supose I could get it to remove all the excess before submitting the form.

Comment: How are you getting the content from TinyMCE? The various data-mce-xxxx attributes are internal markers used during the editing process but they should not be returned when using getContent().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you getting the content from TinyMCE?  The various `data-mce-xxxx` attributes are internal markers used during the editing process but they should not be returned when using `getContent()`.

If I create a simple TinyMCE Fiddle and create content with the two characters as either superscript or subscript I don't get this extra markup when extracting the content:

https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/57haab

Comment: Brilliant. That really helped me.